# Magento 2 - Event dispatched when user click “Proceed To Checkout”

Tags: magento2, php

What is the name of the event that is dispatched when a customer clicks on **"Proceed To Checkout"** after adding stuff to their cart? I want to register that a user started a checkout process for analytics. Specifically, I need to capture the contents of the cart and other information such as total price etc.

I've tried most of the events on [this link](http://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/) that are related to either **"checkout"** or **"cart"**. None of them seem to be dispatched when a user clicks **"Proceed To Checkout"**. The nearest that I could get was

> controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index

which is dispatched when a user clicks **"View and Edit Cart"**.

I'm looking at a couple of ways to solve this.

Get the name of the event that is dispatched when a user clicks **"Proceed To Checkout"**. Observe that event and **"hook"** my code to it.
Or is there a way to see all the events that are being dispatched in real time? I'm thinking that I might be able to find some other event that is dispatched near the same time as checkout and then observe that one.

Comment: for know which event is calling run  `php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable`

Comment: If Muhammad Hasham got answer,Kindly post answer

Comment: It's may be late but just adding that did you tried `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index` or `controller_action_predispatch_checkout` ?  i got logs when clicked on **Proceed to Checkout**